# Multiple yield calls overwrites previous state

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm using Flutter Bloc for state management in my application.

When yielding multiple new states in succession with the .copyWith() pattern,
the members of the state that are not included in the latest .copyWith() calls are set to null.

Is this behaviour intended, or is my flutter and/or Bloc versions too old?
I'm using Flutter 1.22.6 and Flutter_bloc 6.1.3

```
//my_bloc_state.dart
class MyState extends Equatable {
  final String foo;
  final String bar;

  const MyState({this.foo, this.bar});


  MyState copyWith({
    String foo,
    String bar,
  }) {
    if ((foo == null || identical(foo, this.foo)) &&
        (bar == null || identical(bar, this.bar))) {
      return this;
    }

    return MyState(
      foo: foo ?? this.foo,
      bar: bar ?? this.bar
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [foo, bar];
}



//my_bloc.dart

@override
Stream<MyState> mapEventToState(MyEvent event) async* {
  if (event is MySpecialEvent) {
    yield state.copyWith(foo: "hello");

    yield state.copyWith(bar: "World");

    print(state.foo) // null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend updating your libraries in any case, it would be easier for other dependencies in the future.
Other thing I would recommend is to use the `Cubit` approach and your code already looks more like it than the original `BLoC` (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc).
When using `BLoC` it is recommended to have an event for each possible change of the state.

But let's have a look at your problem here.
This snippet:

```
return MyState(
  foo: foo ?? this.foo,
  bar: bar ?? this.bar
);
```

means that `MyState` will update `foo` and `bar` only if they are not null, in case of null it will return whatever was there before.
What does not look good to me is that your `state` object is not yet updated with `yield` but you are trying to print it:

```
print(state.foo) // null
```

If you really want to see how your state object will look like after the `yield` try to add something like this before:

```
state = state.copyWith(foo: "hello");
print(state.foo);
print(state.bar);

state = state.copyWith(bar: "World");
print(state.foo);
print(state.bar);

yield state;
```

Comment: Hello and thanks for your input! I'll be sure to update the libraries as soon as I get to update to null-safety..
The print call is meant to be inside a BlocBuilder somewhere in the component tree.
My question is badly worded however. Can you only yield ONE state from each call to mapEventToState() triggered by an event?

Answer (score 0):

think here is the issue

```
   @override
Stream<MyState> mapEventToState(MyEvent event) async* {
  if (event is MySpecialEvent) {
    yield state.copyWith(foo: "hello");

    yield state.copyWith(bar: "World");

    print(state.foo) // null
  }
}
```

when you print foo after this

```
yield state.copyWith(bar: "World");
```

foo value is null because you are not putting here any value for it.

```
yield state.copyWith(foo: "hello");
```

after this state foo value is "hello" and bar value is null by default.

```
yield state.copyWith(bar: "World");
```

after this state override the previous state values so bar value is "world" and foo value is null by default.

If you need to get both for the last state yield final state as follows.

replace the last yield line

```
yield state.copyWith(bar: "World",foo: "hello");

or 
yield state.copyWith(bar: "World",foo: state.foo);
```

both will work